# Replace all occurrences of a string in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm working on a data frame that has non-detects which are coded with '<'.  Sometimes there is a space after the '<' and sometimes not e.g. '<2' or '< 2'.  I'd like to remove every occurrence of the space.

Example:

```
data <- data.frame(name = rep(letters[1:3], each = 3), var1 = rep('< 2', 9), var2 = rep('<3', 9))

  name var1 var2 
1    a  < 2   <3
2    b  < 2   <3
3    c  < 2   <3
```

This is where I've got to:

I can extract all the values and make the new strings but I can't put them back in the data frame.

```
index <- str_detect(unlist(data), '<')
index <- matrix(index, nrow = 3)

data[index] 
#[1] "< 2" "< 2" "< 2" "<3"  "<3"  "<3" 

replacements <- str_replace_all(data[index], "<[ ]+","<") 
replacements
#[1] "<2" "<2" "<2" "<3" "<3" "<3"

data[index] <- replacements

#Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, index, value = c("<2", "<2", "<2",  : 
#  unsupported matrix index in replacement
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

If you are **only** looking to replace all occurrences of `"< "` (with space) with `"<"` (no space), then you can do an `lapply` over the data frame, with a `gsub` for replacement:

```
> data <- data.frame(lapply(data, function(x) {
+                  gsub("< ", "<", x)
+              }))
> data
  name var1 var2
1    a   <2   <3
2    a   <2   <3
3    a   <2   <3
4    b   <2   <3
5    b   <2   <3
6    b   <2   <3
7    c   <2   <3
8    c   <2   <3
9    c   <2   <3
```

Comment: Use `lapply` instead - it will save the coercion to a matrix.

Comment: `data.frame(lapply(data, function(x) {gsub("<\\s*", "<", x)}))`

Comment: This will transform the object to a list, so you need `data <- as.data.frame(data)` after that. Or of course the solution in the comment above, from Avinash Raj. Last thing: it's 2017, so we now write `data <- data %>% as.data.frame()`

Comment: `data.frame(lapply(data, function(x) gsub("< ", "<", x), stringsAsFactors=F)` will avoid converting characters to factors, just in case...

Comment: the only problem with this method is that it changes all type of columns to character format

Answer (score 68):

Equivalent to "find and replace." Don't overthink it.

Try it with one:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(name = rep(letters[1:3], each = 3), var1 = rep('< 2', 9), var2 = rep('<3', 9))

df %>% 
  mutate(var1 = str_replace(var1, " ", ""))
#>   name var1 var2
#> 1    a   <2   <3
#> 2    a   <2   <3
#> 3    a   <2   <3
#> 4    b   <2   <3
#> 5    b   <2   <3
#> 6    b   <2   <3
#> 7    c   <2   <3
#> 8    c   <2   <3
#> 9    c   <2   <3
```

Apply to all

```
df %>% 
  mutate_all(funs(str_replace(., " ", "")))
#>   name var1 var2
#> 1    a   <2   <3
#> 2    a   <2   <3
#> 3    a   <2   <3
#> 4    b   <2   <3
#> 5    b   <2   <3
#> 6    b   <2   <3
#> 7    c   <2   <3
#> 8    c   <2   <3
#> 9    c   <2   <3
```

If the extra space was produced by uniting columns, think about making `str_trim` part of your workflow.

Created on 2018-03-11 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: very nice, I would instead use str_replace_all:
`df %>% 
  mutate_all(funs(str_replace_all(., " ", "")))`

Comment: Just for the record: I tried `df %>% mutate_all(str_replace_all, " ", "")` 
Seems to work. Brief and legible. NB: coerces factors to characters!

Comment: one note - we now write `data <- data %>% as.data.frame()`

Answer (score 20):

To remove all spaces in every column, you can use

```
data[] <- lapply(data, gsub, pattern = " ", replacement = "", fixed = TRUE)
```

or to constrict this to just the second and third columns (i.e. every column except the first),

```
data[-1] <- lapply(data[-1], gsub, pattern = " ", replacement = "", fixed = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 11):

Here is a dplyr solution

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

Censor_consistently <-  function(x){
  str_replace(x, '^\\s*([<>])\\s*(\\d+)', '\\1\\2')
}


test_df <- tibble(x = c('0.001', '<0.002', ' < 0.003', ' >  100'),  y = 4:1)

mutate_all(test_df, funs(Censor_consistently))

# A tibble: 4 × 2
x     y
<chr> <chr>
1  0.001     4
2 <0.002     3
3 <0.003     2
4   >100     1
```

Answer (score 10):

As an update to the [answer by @Nettle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49222212/7002525), `mutate_all()` has been superseded by [`mutate( across( ... ) )`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html):

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
    name = rep( letters[1:3], each = 3 ),
    var1 = rep( '< 2', 9 ),
    var2 = rep( '<3', 9 )
)

df %>%
    mutate( across(
        .cols = everything(),
        ~str_replace( ., " ", "" )
    ) )

#>   name var1 var2
#> 1    a   <2   <3
#> 2    a   <2   <3
#> 3    a   <2   <3
#> 4    b   <2   <3
#> 5    b   <2   <3
#> 6    b   <2   <3
#> 7    c   <2   <3
#> 8    c   <2   <3
#> 9    c   <2   <3
```

Answer (score 5):

I had  the problem, I had to replace "Not Available" with `NA` and my solution goes like this

```
data <- sapply(data,function(x) {x <- gsub("Not Available",NA,x)})
```

Answer (score 1):

late to the party. but if you only want to get rid of leading/trailing white space, R base has a function `trimws`

For example:

```
data <- apply(X = data, MARGIN = 2, FUN = trimws) %>% as.data.frame()
```