# Using dplyr, Remove all strings from a data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with 300 columns which has a string variable somewhere which I am trying to remove. I have found this solution in stack overflow using `lapply` (see below), which is what I want to do, but using the `dplyr` package. I have tried using the `mutate_each` function but cant seem to make it work

"If your data frame (df) is really all integers except for NAs and garbage then then the following converts it.

```
df2 <- data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x))))
```

You'll have a warning about NAs introduced by coercion but that's just all those non numeric character strings turning into NAs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use this line of code:

```
df2 <- data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x))))
```

with `dplyr` (by which I assume you mean "using pipes") the easiest would be

```
df2 = df %>% lapply(function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x))) %>%
    as.data.frame
```

To "translate" this into the `mutate_each` idiom:

```
mutate_each(df, funs(as.numeric(as.character(.)))
```

This function will, of course, convert all columns to character, then to numeric. To improve efficiency, don't bother doing two conversions on columns that are already numeric:

```
mutate_each(df, funs({
    if (is.numeric(.)) return(.)
    as.numeric(as.character(.))
}))
```

Data for testing:

```
df = data.frame(v1 = 1:10, v2 = factor(11:20))
```

Answer (score 4):

`dplyr` 0.5 now includes a `select_if()` function.
For example:

```
person <- c("jim", "john", "harry")
df <- data.frame(matrix(c(1:9,NA,11,12), nrow=3), person)

library(dplyr)
df %>% select_if(is.numeric)

#  X1 X2 X3 X4
#1  1  4  7 NA
#2  2  5  8 11
#3  3  6  9 12
```

Of course you could add further conditions if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

***mutate_all*** works here, and simply wrap the gsub in a function. (I also assume you aren't necessarily string hunting, so much as trawling for non-integers.

```
StrScrub <- function(x) {
    as.integer(gsub("^\\D+$",NA, x))
    }
ScrubbedDF <- mutate_all(data, funs(StrScrub))
```

Example dataframe:

```
library(dplyr)
options(stringsAsFactors = F)
data = data.frame("A" = c(2:5),"B" = c(5,"gr",3:2), "C" = c("h", 9, "j", "1"))
```

with reference/help from [Tony Ladson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39480500/5088194)