# How do I replace all the instances of a certain character in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that has many instances of '?' in different rows with dtype 'object'.

How can I replace all the '?' with 0.

Comment: Similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29271549/replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-a-data-frame

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['?', 1], [2, '?']])

print(df)

   0  1
0  ?  1
1  2  ?
```

**`replace`**

```
df.replace('?', 0)

   0  1
0  0  1
1  2  0
```

**`mask` or `where`**

```
df.mask(df == '?', 0)
# df.where(df != '?', 0)

   0  1
0  0  1
1  2  0
```

---

However, imagine your dataframe has `?` within longer strings.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['a?', 1], [2, '?b']])

print(df)

    0   1
0  a?   1
1   2  ?b
```

**`replace` with `regex=True`**

```
df.replace('\?', '0', regex=True)

    0   1
0  a0   1
1   2  0b
```

Answer (score 3):

I think better is [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) it to `string` `0`, because else get mixed types - numeric with strings and some pandas function can failed:

```
df.replace('?', '0')
```

Also if need replace multiple `?` to one `0` add `+` for match one or more values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['a???', '?'], ['s?', '???b']])
print(df)
      0     1
0  a???     ?
1    s?  ???b

df = df.replace('\?+', '0', regex=True)
print (df)
    0   1
0  a0   0
1  s0  0b
```

---

```
df = df.replace('[?]+', '0', regex=True)
print (df)
    0   1
0  a0   0
1  s0  0b
```