# String replacement in table

Tags: r

I am trying to fetch [CoinMarketCap](https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/views/all/) price chart. I did:

```
url_cmp <- "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/views/all/"
library(rvest)

url_cmp %>%
read_html() %>%
html_nodes(css = "table") %>%
html_table() -> "tbl_cmp"
```

Now I've the entire table and would like to clean it up. I'd like remove the all `$`, `%`,`,`, `\n` characters from the table. I tried:

```
stringr::str_replace_all(string = tbl_cmp, pattern = "\\\n|\\s|[%*$,]", replacement = "")
```

and

```
gsub(pattern = "\\\n|\\s|[%*$,]", replacement = "", x = df_cmp)
```

Both do intended replacement, but the table format is no longer retained; I get a long string. I understand that both `str_replace()` and `gsub()` take string as input. Is there a workaround for table?

Comment: I'd recommend you lapply the gsub function across the columns so to retain the structure: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29271549/replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-a-data-frame

Comment: Maybe something like `as.data.frame(sapply(tbl_cmp[[1]], function(i) gsub('[[:punct:]]|\\\n', '', i)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new_df <- tbl_cmp[[1]] %>% sapply(gsub,pattern = "\\\n|\\s|[%*$,]", replacement = "") %>% as.data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
num_cols <- names(new_df)[-(2:3)]
conv_col_to_num <- function(x){if(x %in% num_cols) new_df[[x]] %>% as.numeric %>% data.frame else new_df[[x]] %>% data.frame}
new_df_num <-
  new_df %>% 
  names %>% 
  lapply(conv_col_to_num) %>%
  do.call(cbind,.) %>%
  setNames(names(new_df))

# > head(new_df_num)
#   #            Name Symbol  Market Cap       Price Circulating Supply Volume (24h)  % 1h % 24h   % 7d
# 1 1         Bitcoin    BTC 40690438752 2481.970000           16394412   1406060000  0.03  8.06 -12.62
# 2 2        Ethereum    ETH 33960266690  367.000000           92535795   1554170000 -0.02 15.09  35.91
# 3 3          Ripple    XRP 10036645930    0.262120        38290271363    109902000 -0.04  4.58  -9.87
# 4 4             NEM    XEM  1784268000    0.198252         8999999999      7966520  0.60 13.42 -10.20
# 5 5 EthereumClassic    ETC  1687441250   18.210000           92656987    108333000 -0.28  8.45   4.40
# 6 6        Litecoin    LTC  1649935702   31.990000           51575157    365949000  2.24 14.14   6.57

# > str(new_df_num)
# 'data.frame':  754 obs. of  10 variables:
#   $ #                 : num  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#   $ Name              : Factor w/ 751 levels "1337","1CRedit",..: 74 245 558 446 246 395 179 358 90 616 ...
# $ Symbol            : Factor w/ 751 levels "","1337","1CR",..: 98 236 718 695 235 377 169 402 106 579 ...
# $ Market Cap        : num  4.07e+10 3.40e+10 1.00e+10 1.78e+09 1.69e+09 ...
# $ Price             : num  2481.97 367 0.262 0.198 18.21 ...
# $ Circulating Supply: num  1.64e+07 9.25e+07 3.83e+10 9.00e+09 9.27e+07 ...
# $ Volume (24h)      : num  1.41e+09 1.55e+09 1.10e+08 7.97e+06 1.08e+08 ...
# $ % 1h              : num  0.03 -0.02 -0.04 0.6 -0.28 2.24 0.09 1.5 -0.29 -0.71 ...
# $ % 24h             : num  8.06 15.09 4.58 13.42 8.45 ...
# $ % 7d              : num  -12.62 35.91 -9.87 -10.2 4.4 ...
```

Note :
I added code to end up with a properly formatted data.frame (with numeric columns).

I tried to be more consistent with the pipes and replaced apply by sapply (see comments).

I think (I'm not sure) that apply converts to matrix at the input while sapply does it only at the output, so if my function had to work with numbers (it doesn't), apply would have failed.

"?" are turned into NAs, hence the warnings

Comment: Wonderful! I forgot the powerful `apply()` family of functions.

Comment: Two things. 1: It's better to use `sapply` rather than `apply` with `MARGIN = 2`. And 2: Why do you need to use pipping? what's wrong with `as.data.frame(.....)`?

Comment: OP was using piping so I used it as well, I felt it was also more readable, and I'm myself trying to use pipes more. Nothing is wrong with as.data.frame()

Comment: How can convert the number values (price, etc.) to type `numeric` in one go, using something similar to `apply()`?

Comment: I didn't find an elegant way to do it in one operation, but here you have it in 2 :)