# Change words starting with pattern

Tags: r, text, nlp, speech, dialect

I am analysing political speech and want to standardize some dialect words. I want to change all words starting with "fra" so that they start with "fre".

Example:

*"frad walked into a bar"* becomes *"fred walked into a bar"*

*"are you frad"* becomes *"are you fred"*

*"are you afraid"* should not change, and stay the same

How do I do this in R?

The speeches are stored in a data frame together with some metadata, where the variable **text** stores speech for each politician within a year.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace all occurrences of a string in a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29271549/replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-a-data-frame)

Comment: I think not quite since the string should only be replaced if at the start of a word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are lookin for are called regular expressions:

```
text <- c("frad walked into a bar", "are you frad", "are you afraid")

gsub("\\bfra", "fre", text)
#> [1] "fred walked into a bar" "are you fred"           "are you afraid"
```

In this case, the `\\b` means beginning or end of word. You can use this [cheat sheet](https://rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/RegExCheatsheet.pdf) to learn more or find another good resource.

Comment: Why not use "\\<"?

Comment: Try `gsub("\\bfra", "fre", 'frad is fragile')`

Comment: I've never heard of `"\\<"` before but seems to do the same thing. "frad is fragile" seems to work as intended ("fred is fregile"). What is your point, @Sotos?

Comment: My point being that fragile should not have changed and this task might be much more complicated than presented. But If OP is good with that, then all is good I guess.

Comment: In my case the most important is that politicians with different dialects use the same word if it conveys the same meaning (Fred should be either Fred or Frad). So changing fragile to fregile doesn't matter much in this analysis, as long as there's only one version of the word. Thanks to all of you!