# Apply a function to each column in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, apply, lapply

I would like to replace a series of "99"s in my dataframe with NA. To do this for one column I am using the following line of code, which works just fine.

`data$column[data$column == "99"] = NA`

However, as I have a large number of columns I want to apply this to all columns. The following line of code isn't doing it. I assume it is because the third "x" is again a reference to the dataframe and not to a specific column.

`data = lapply(data, function(x) {x[x == "99"] = NA})`

Any advice on what I should change?

Comment: Duplicate question. You can get the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29271549/replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-a-data-frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace all 99, simply do

```
data[data=="99"] <- NA
```

If you want to stick to the apply function

```
apply(data, 2, function(x) replace(x, x=="99", NA))
```