# How to replace multiple different data in a column with another data in another column in R programming?

Tags: r, dataframe

| Hometeam | Awayteam | FTR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| liverpool | unicorn | H |
| west ham. | jibb. | D. |
| Man City. | joker. | A. |
| Bournemouth. | house. | H. |
| Sheffield. | superman. | A. |

How do I replace `H` with data from `Hometeam`, `A` with `Awayteam`, and `D` with the word `Draw` all in one shot?

I tried using `str_replace` but it only works with one specific data.... Help pls

Comment: Please consider adding the data to your question instead of an image. It helps reproduce the problem in an efficient way.

Comment: You can get the sample data by running `dput(df)` in your R console.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace all occurrences of a string in a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29271549/replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-a-data-frame)

Comment: @VishalA. hi !  thanks for replying . I have reproduced the image in data form. and nope, this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29271549/replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-a-data-frame doesn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use `case_when` inside of `mutate`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(FTR = case_when(FTR == "H" ~ HomeTeam,
                         FTR == "A" ~ AwayTeam,
                         FTR == "D" ~ "Draw"))
```

**Output**

```
     HomeTeam         AwayTeam       FTR
1   Liverpool          Norwich Liverpool
2    West Ham         Man City  Man City
3 Bournemouth Sheffield United      Draw
```

Or if you want to stick to `str_replace`, then you can also use it inside of `case_when`.

```
df %>%
  mutate(FTR = case_when(
    str_detect(FTR, "H") ~ HomeTeam,
    str_detect(FTR, "A") ~ AwayTeam,
    str_detect(FTR, "D") ~ "Draw"
  ))
```

**Data**

```
df <-
  structure(
    list(
      HomeTeam = c("Liverpool", "West Ham", "Bournemouth"),
      AwayTeam = c("Norwich", "Man City", "Sheffield United"),
      FTR = c("H",
              "A", "D")
    ),
    class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c(NA,-3L)
  )
```