# Replacing characters in column names

Tags: r

My data frame contains headers with dots, which I would like to replace with underscores.

Sample data:

```
myheaders = c("3.1","3.2","3.3","3.4","3.5","3.6")
mydata = c(2,0,3,1,1,4)
example = as.data.frame(t(mydata))
colnames(example) <- myheaders
example

> example
  3.1 3.2 3.3 3.4 3.5 3.6
1   2   0   3   1   1   4
```

Following [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29271549/replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-a-data-frame), I've tried this:

```
myoutput <- data.frame(lapply(example, function(x) {gsub(".", "_", x, fixed = TRUE)}))
```

However, this just introduces "X" into the headers. Where is the mistake?

```
> myoutput
  X3.1 X3.2 X3.3 X3.4 X3.5 X3.6
1    2    0    3    1    1    4
```

This is my desired output:

```
> myoutput
   3_1  3_2  3_3  3_4  3_5   3_6
1    2    0    3    1    1    4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to change the column names, so should use `colnames`, otherwise you are applying the function to your data.frame (excluding column (or row) names).

```r
colnames(example) <- gsub(".", "_", colnames(example), fixed = TRUE)
#   3_1 3_2 3_3 3_4 3_5 3_6
# 1   2   0   3   1   1   4
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `names()`, this should do the trick:

```r
names(example) <- gsub("\\.", "_", names(example))
example
#>   3_1 3_2 3_3 3_4 3_5 3_6
#> 1   2   0   3   1   1   4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
new_colnames <- gsub("\\.", "_", colnames(example))
colnames(example) <- new_colnames

example
#   3_1 3_2 3_3 3_4 3_5 3_6
# 1   2   0   3   1   1   4
```

`gsub` does what you need (you can replace the fixed argument by escapping the dot using \\ ), but it changes the strings in the vector of colnames. And then change the colnames like you did in your example using the `colnames()` function.